# Laravel convert database Json data to JSON object use in React-native

Tags: php, database, laravel, react-native

My DB data is

```
ID  Data
01  {vipmember:{Name:John,Point:32000}}
02  {silvermember:{Name:Mark,Point:28000}}
03  {normalmember:{Name:Nick,Point:16000}}
```

I use laravel code to export in json like

```
foreach ($noti as $not){
        array_push($data,$not->data);
      }
      return response()->json([
          'member' => $data,
      ]);
```

but I log in console to set state this.state.json.data.vipmember is undefined
how I can convert to object

Comment: Check out this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: `this.state.json.data.member.vipmember`

Comment: I try to array casting but still undefined in `this.state.json.data.member.vipmember`